# establishing push notification in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

i have to implement push notification in my project.
It has sender(windows phone window application),wcf service and client(windows phone applcation).

How can i replace the sender and use my url to send and recieve notification from client?

i want sender to be some application in emulator itself that run parallely with the client and push data continously to the client.

how to develop such application

can anyone tell the way.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow what you mean.  please clarify your question.  Also, notifications are one-way, so you can't use them to "send and receive notification from the client"

Comment: i edit the question now u understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though you are looking to use two WP7 apps to send messages back and forth to one another using the push notification functionality. Is that correct?

My understanding it that you will still require a each device to subscribe to a push notification service (MS hosted) using the unique URI sent back when the subscription is successful. It appears that SL3/4 can create HttpWebRequest objects and therefore should be able to formulate a correct package to send, however, the difficulty as I see it will be how to obtain the URI of the device you want to send the post to. Normally the post is sent to the subscriber, which knows its on URI as it was returned during the subscribing phase.

My WCF hosted code only works if the WCF knows the URI of the device, which is sent when the WCF method is called:

```
    public bool sendTileUpdate(string tileText, string url, string image)
    {
        string TilePushXML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
                "<wp:Tile>" +
                "<wp:BackgroundImage>{2}</wp:BackgroundImage>" +
                "<wp:Count>{0}</wp:Count>" +
                "<wp:Title>{1}</wp:Title>" +
                "</wp:Tile>" +
                "</wp:Notification>";

        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest sendNotificationRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            sendNotificationRequest.Method = "POST";
            sendNotificationRequest.Headers = new WebHeaderCollection();
            sendNotificationRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";

            // Tile
            sendNotificationRequest.Headers.Add("X-WindowsPhone-Target", "token");
            sendNotificationRequest.Headers.Add("X-NotificationClass", "1");

            string str = string.Format(TilePushXML, "", tileText, image);

            byte[] strBytes = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(str);
            sendNotificationRequest.ContentLength = strBytes.Length;
            using (Stream requestStream = sendNotificationRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(strBytes, 0, strBytes.Length);
            }
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)sendNotificationRequest.GetResponse();
            string notificationStatus = response.Headers["X-NotificationStatus"];
            string deviceConnectionStatus = response.Headers["X-DeviceConnectionStatus"];
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I know this is a TileNotification, but the principles are the same.

I understand that Mango (WP7.1 & SL4) will support [sockets](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/80778/488364.aspx) and this might be a more appropriate way for your devices to communicate!

Good luck,

Jason.